# User Edit and Delete routes are providing errors, namespace routing

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, rails-routing

I have a problem with my routes, and I think it's due to params being passed incorrectly. Whenever I try to go the the users edit page, I get the following error:

```
No route matches {:action=>"edit", :controller=>"admin/users", :locale=>#<User id: 10, first_name: "Chase", last_name: "Jensen", email: "email@email.com", password_digest: "$2a$10$xTvG5gP73w2/nVW5jD.BSO3Z46S5v9oGogmfjo3gsGHf...", access_level: 2, last_login: nil, auth_token: nil, created_at: "2012-04-20 02:19:33", updated_at: "2012-04-20 02:19:33">}
```

I have noticed that it's saying :locale=>#User ID (hash) but i'm not sure if that's the problem. If it is, I don't know why it's putting the user hash as :locale? Here is some of my app code

code that it's complaining about:
app/views/admin/users/index.html.erb

```
<% @owners.each do |owner| %>
  <%= owner.first_name %>
  <%= link_to "Edit Owner", edit_admin_user_path(owner) %>
  <%= link_to "Delete Owner", admin_user_path(owner), :method => :delete, :confirm => "Are you sure you want to delete this owner?" %>
<% end %>
```

Users Controller

```
class Admin::UsersController < Admin::BaseController
  def edit
    @user = User.find(params[:id])
  end
  def update
    @user = User.find(params[:id])

    if @user.update_attributes(params[:user])
      flash[:notice] = "User has been updated."
      redirect_to @user
    else 
      flash[:alert] = "User has not been updated."
      render :action => "edit"
    end
  end
  def index
    @owners = User.all
  end
end
```

routes.rb (shortened)

```
scope ":locale", locale: /#{I18n.available_locales.join("|")}/ do
  namespace :admin do
    resources :users do
      collection do
        get :newowner
      end
    end
  end
end
```

rake routes output

```
newowner_admin_users GET    /:locale/admin/users/newowner(.:format) {:locale=>/en|es/, :action=>"newowner", :controller=>"admin/users"}
     admin_users GET    /:locale/admin/users(.:format)          {:locale=>/en|es/, :action=>"index", :controller=>"admin/users"}
                 POST   /:locale/admin/users(.:format)          {:locale=>/en|es/, :action=>"create", :controller=>"admin/users"}
  new_admin_user GET    /:locale/admin/users/new(.:format)      {:locale=>/en|es/, :action=>"new", :controller=>"admin/users"}
 edit_admin_user GET    /:locale/admin/users/:id/edit(.:format) {:locale=>/en|es/, :action=>"edit", :controller=>"admin/users"}
      admin_user GET    /:locale/admin/users/:id(.:format)      {:locale=>/en|es/, :action=>"show", :controller=>"admin/users"}
                 PUT    /:locale/admin/users/:id(.:format)      {:locale=>/en|es/, :action=>"update", :controller=>"admin/users"}
                 DELETE /:locale/admin/users/:id(.:format)      {:locale=>/en|es/, :action=>"destroy", :controller=>"admin/users"}
```

I am so confused why I am getting this error, when the routes seem to match up. Anyone have any insight on this? Thanks in advance.

**Edit:**

At this point locale should be set in the application controller

```
before_filter :set_locale

private
def set_locale
  I18n.locale = params[:locale] if params[:locale].present?
end
```

and in my application view
app/views/layouts/application.html.erb

```
<%= link_to_unless_current "English", locale: "en" %> |
<%= link_to_unless_current "Spanish", locale: "es" %>
```

And doesn't it default to EN?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Adding this to my application controller, as specified in Ryan Bates railscast fixed it.

```
def default_url_options(options = {})
  {locale: I18n.locale}
end
```

Answer (score 0):

You didn't pass the locale argument
Try `edit_admin_user_path(owner, :locale => "en")`

Comment: Hmm that didn't seem to work, I think should already be set at this point, see my edit